# Integer solutions to $42k+3^{6k-1}-11=n^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Integer solutions to $42k+3^{6k-1}-11=n^2$

I think there are no integer solutions $(k,n)$ satisfying the equation. So I guess that if there is a number $q$ such that $LHS \neq RHS \pmod q$ we are done.

For example if $q=6$ then $LHS \equiv 4 \pmod 6 \quad \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$ but the possible values of $n^2 \pmod 6$ are $\{0, 1, 3, 4\}$. Thus it can be $LHS \equiv RHS \equiv 4$ so $q=6$ isn't very helpful.

Comment: There are no solutions for $k<1000$ (corresponding to $n<1.78\cdot10^{2862}$. Note that $k$ has to be natural for the left-hand side to be an integer, so $k\geq 1$). However, I doubt whether the method $\text{LHS}\not\equiv \text{RHS}\mod q$ will work, since a little bit of testing shows that $q$ has to be quite large (larger than $3571$, the $500$th prime).

Comment: user, where did you get this problem?

Comment: a friend sent me it. Is it possible to solve it by induction?

Comment: By $\pmod 2$ we get that $n=2a$ for some integer $a$. By $\pmod 3$ we get that $n=3b+1$ or $n=3b+2$ for some integer $b$ and by $\pmod 6$ we get that $n=6c+2$ or $n=6c+4$ for some integer $c$. By those I think we can conclude that $n=-2$ when $n \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and $n \equiv 4 \pmod 6$. Is that wrong?